# Capitalize second item in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to capitalize the second word in the array, I tried it based on the index number, however I get undefined for `array[i+1]`. Is there another way?

```js
const filteredSegments = segments.map((segment, i, array) => {
    const hide = i === 0 && new RegExp(namePatterns.join('|'), 'i').test(segment.words)
    const next = array[i + 1]

    if (hide && next) { next.words.toUpperCase() }
    return { ...segment, words: hide ? segment.words.replace(/./g, '\u200c') : segment.words }
})
```

Comment: How is this being used? What input is given?

Comment: input changes often depending on the recording time

Comment: We need an example or we're probably going to get it wrong.

Comment: Your question is still a bit ambiguous, add the input and output which you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the second item?

```js
function capitalizeSecondItem(arr) {
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    arr[1] = arr[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[1].slice(1);
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(capitalizeSecondItem(['hello', 'world']));
console.log(capitalizeSecondItem(['foo']));
console.log(capitalizeSecondItem([]));
console.log(capitalizeSecondItem(['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Counts even and odd in the loop and changes every second record

```js
var arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipisicing', 'elit', 'esse', 'voluptatibus', 'illum', 'fuga', 'quae', 'consequatur', 'pariatur']


for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

**Second option:**
Another way to solve the task is if we loop the array through two values

```js
var arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipisicing', 'elit', 'esse', 'voluptatibus', 'illum', 'fuga', 'quae', 'consequatur', 'pariatur']

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length;  i += 2) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

**Answer the question from the comment below the post:**

*("I want to capitalize only the second word if the first is empty string")*

The code checks if the first string in the array is empty and if there is a second string if the condition is true... it performs the task of the second.

If there is a first string, it performs the task of the first -> *(If you don't need it this, just remove the `else`)*

```js
var arr = ['', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'adipisicing', 'elit', 'esse', 'voluptatibus', 'illum', 'fuga', 'quae', 'consequatur', 'pariatur']


if (arr[0].length === 0 && arr.length > 1) {
    arr[1] = arr[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[1].slice(1);
} else {
    arr[0] = arr[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[0].slice(1);
}


console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I want to capitalize only the second word if the first first is empty string, in your code its capitalizing every even number. The problem is array I'm mapping changes often, it might not have a second item, when accessing it via `arr[i`]`

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing only second Word, for that, we don't have to iterate the array,
Just check it array is bigger than or equal to length 2 and if yes then just capitalize the
second word and keep remaining element as it is, its more time efficient too
as we just have to perform on lookup in one certain index rather than iterating the whole array:

```js
let segment = ["", "to", "capitalize", "the","second","word","in","the","array"];

if(segment.length >=2){
   segment[1] = segment[1][0].toUpperCase() + segment[1].substr(1);
}

console.log(segment );
```

Capitalize second Word if first element is empty string:

```js
let segment = [
  "",
  "want",
  "to",
  "capitalize",
  "the",
  "second",
  "word",
  "in",
  "t",
  "array",
];

let sentense = segment.join(" ").trim();
sentense = sentense[0].toUpperCase() + sentense.substr(1);

console.log(sentense.split(" "));
```